# How to change/add field in JSON structure in angularjs/javascript

Tags: javascript, json

i am using angularjs http get method to get the data,the JSON format which i am getting is :

```
{"SITE1":[
    {
        "name":"name1",
        "status":"0",
        "id":23,
        "isDeleted":false
    },
    {
        "name":"name2",
        "status":"0",
        "id":13,
        "isDeleted":false
    }],

"SITE2":[
    {
        "name":"name3",
        "status":"0",
        "id":2,
        "isDeleted":false
    }
    ]}
```

but i want data to be in format

```
{"location" : "SITE1",
 "services" : [
      {
        "name":"name1",
        "status":"0",
        "id":23,
        "isDeleted":false
      },
      {
        "name":"name2",
        "status":"0",
        "id":13,
        "isDeleted":false
      }],
   "location" : "SITE2",
    "services":[
       {
        "name":"name3",
        "status":"0",
        "id":2,
        "isDeleted":false
       }
    ]}
```

Please help in this, how to do this. 
I tried using

```
object["location"] = key;
 object["status"] = value;
```

to add these fields. but something is going wrong in this.

Comment: Sorry, but the version you want means you want a **single** object to have the same property **multiple** times. This makes no sense.

Comment: you might want to use an array of objects, such as [ { "location":"SITE1", "services":[{...}]}, {"location":"SITE2", "services":[{...}] } ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request won't work, as stated by "Nowhere man" because you are setting different values to the same key at the moment so that only the last one will be shown. The best solution in my opinion is to have an array of objects.

```
var temp=[];
angular.forEach(values, function(data, index){
    var tempObj={};
    tempObj.location=index;
    tempObj.services=data;
    temp.push(tempObj);
});
return temp;
```

See this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/5UdDEl?p=preview